# Issue with sending object to another class's method

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I want to use - (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect to manage some nice output to UIViewController. That for I've created a UIView subclass. Now I can output a picture to UIViewController. Now I've faced a problem how to pass to UIView subclass an object that contains all the data needed for topics, texts etc.., and this object was created in UIViewController class.

I do create the object this way:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

self.setQualityButton.hidden=YES;
//[self setTheItem:theItem];
[drawItemDetails setTheItem:theItem]; //drawItemDetails is my UIView subclass
//theItem is an object I've retained from TableView and it's not empty
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}
```

In drawItemDetails( UIView subclass):

```
-(void)setTheItem:(ItemShow*)inputTheItem;
{
if(theItem!=inputTheItem)
{
    [theItem release];
    theItem=inputTheItem;
    [theItem retain];
}
[self setNeedsDisplay];
NSLog(@"%@",theItem.itemYear); //output null
}
```

What's wrong and does this data-pass approach makes cense at all?

Comment: First off, your topic talks about class methods, but your question only refers to instance methods. What do class methods have to do with anything? Second, what makes you think there's anything wrong with the "data-pass approach" you illustrate here? Does it not work? Why not? Finally, you technically shouldn't `release` an ivar until the new one is set. So your setter should look like: `ItemShow *oldItem = theItem; theItem = [inputTheItem retain]; [oldItem release];`

Comment: @jemmons I think it's pretty clear from the context that the OP is asking about calling a *method of a class* rather than a *class method*. I've made the "class" in the title posessive to solve that problem.

Comment: @Caleb I don't see that a "method of a class" is any different than a "class method". At best it's ambiguous, and there's an obvious alternative ("instance method"). But even accepting your interpretation, why does the OP think the issue is with sending an object to an instance of another class? There's no mention of "other class-ness" causing a problem in the question.

Comment: @jemmons Beginners often have trouble using exactly the right terminology, and for some reason the realm of sending messages between objects seems particularly difficult. Edit the question and/or title if you can improve them. I agree with you that the content of the question is unclear, and I won't be surprised to see more downvotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Passing data to the view like that is fine -- you're doing approximately the same thing you'd do if you were setting the text of a UILabel.

What you seem to be doing with your custom view's `-drawRect:` sounds weird/wrong, though. Any view's `-drawRect:` should draw the view in the context that has been set up for it, and that's it. It shouldn't care about the view controller, try to pass data to other objects, etc. If you tell us more about what you're trying to accomplish, we can probably offer better alternatives.

Comment: theItem is an object that contains data retrieved from sqlite database. I should get the values by theItem.itemYear etc. I need this object for doing custom drawing on xib canvas.

Comment: The way you're dealing with `theItem` seems to be fine. The part I'm questioning is where you say: "Now I can output a picture to UIViewController." Your `-drawRect:` shoudn't care about the view controller.

Comment: in drawRect method that lives in UIView subclass

Comment: @Nathan *Any* `-drawRect:` method that you write is likely to be in a UIView subclass, so I'm not sure what you're trying to say.

Comment: Yes, this method is in UIView subclass and it works.

Comment: @nathan If it works, then what is your issue? Please explain to us what *doesn't* work.

Comment: -(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    //[self setItemDetails:theItem];
    [[self navigationController]setToolbarHidden:YES animated:YES];
    [drawItemDetails setTheItem:theItem];
}
That was the issue. I had to call the method of UIView class in ViewWillAppear instead of viewDidLoad